Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]
I have an discord bot. whose one function is to find duplicate images from server. After going through less than 1500 messages there seems to be a DNS error. exception to restart the process isn't being trigger as well is there a way a fix it. I am hosting the bot on solarhosting.cc Is there a way to avaoid that?.
def calculate_image_hash(image_data):
    return hashlib.md5(image_data).hexdigest()

# Function to process channels
async def process_channels(ctx, image_data, attachment_filename, target_channel_ids=None):
    found = True
    total_channels = len(ctx.guild.text_channels)
    processed_channels = 0
    processed_messages = 0
    processed_attachments = 0

    if target_channel_ids:
        channels = [ctx.guild.get_channel(channel_id) for channel_id in target_channel_ids]
        channels = [channel for channel in channels if channel]  # Remove None values
        if not channels:
            await ctx.send("Invalid channel IDs provided.")
            return False
    else:
        channels = ctx.guild.text_channels

    # Blacklist of channel IDs to exclude from search
    blacklist_channels = [1108403287524376678, 1133687265575583897, 1142465680927629414, 1226560864564412598, 
                          1141310866650841088, 1141374405780455454, 1135926589792731176,  1135926645748940821, 
                          1136351156453507162, 1225919783036391455]  # Add channel IDs here
    target_channel_set = set(target_channel_ids) if target_channel_ids else set()
    blacklist_channels = list(set(blacklist_channels) - target_channel_set)

    await ctx.send("Channel Loops Has Started.")
    for channel in channels:
        # Check if the channel is in the blacklist
        if channel.id in blacklist_channels:
            continue

        processed_channels += 1
        print(f"Processing channel: {channel.name} ({processed_channels}/{total_channels})")
        try:
            async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
                for message_attachment in message.attachments:
                    processed_messages += 1
                    processed_attachments += 1
                    # Calculate hash for the attachment at runtime
                    attachment_hash = calculate_image_hash(await message_attachment.read())
                    if attachment_hash == image_data:
                        embed = discord.Embed(
                            title="Match Found",
                            description=f"#{channel.name}: [{message_attachment.filename}]({message.jump_url})",
                            color=discord.Color.green()
                        )
                        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                        print(f"Match Found")
                        found = True

                # Apply the check after every 100 messages
                if processed_messages % 50 == 0:
                    print(f"Processed {processed_messages} messages and {processed_attachments} attachments so far...")
                    if processed_messages % 700 == 0:
                        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
                        await ctx.send(f"Processed {processed_messages} messages. Current Channel: {channel.name} so far...")
                if processed_channels/total_channels == 0.5:
                    await ctx.send("Half of the server searched.")
                if processed_channels/total_channels == 0.8:
                    await ctx.send("80% of the server searched.")

        except (discord.errors.HTTPException, discord.errors.Forbidden) as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while processing_channel {channel.name}")
            # Retry processing the current channel
            #await process_channels(ctx, image_data, attachment_filename, target_channel_ids)

    if not found:
        await ctx.send("No matching image found")

# Command to find matching image
@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, *target_channel_ids: int):
    # Check if a message contains an attachment
    if not ctx.message.attachments:
        await ctx.send("No image attached.")
        return

    # Get the content and filename of the attached image
    attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0]
    image_data = await attachment.read()
    image_hash = calculate_image_hash(image_data)
    
    try:
        await process_channels(ctx, image_hash, attachment.filename, target_channel_ids)
    except (discord.errors.HTTPException, discord.errors.Forbidden) as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while processing channel {channel.name} Retrying in 60 sec")
        await asyncio.sleep(60) 
        await process_channels(ctx, image_hash, attachment.filename, target_channel_ids)


error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1203, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await self._resolve_host(host, port, traces=traces)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 880, in _resolve_host
    return await asyncio.shield(resolved_host_task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 917, in _resolve_host_with_throttle
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 33, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 901, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 963, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 180, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/app.py", line 1077, in find
    try:
         
  File "/home/container/app.py", line 1028, in process_channels
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/iterators.py", line 123, in __anext__
    return await self.next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/iterators.py", line 331, in next
    await self.fill_messages()
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/iterators.py", line 354, in fill_messages
    data = await self._retrieve_messages(self.retrieve)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/iterators.py", line 378, in _retrieve_messages_before_strategy
    data: list[MessagePayload] = await self.logs_from(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 285, in request
    async with self.__session.request(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1197, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 581, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 944, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1209, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 959, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 189, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]

